# Nginx setup and v1/** endpoints access

Tags: nginx, docker, jersey

I run my java jersey app in docker container on Ubuntu (aws instance)
Here is some nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name demoapp;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't access hostname/v1/** any api endpoint from browser after deployment, curl -i hostname works fine and returns app headers (version, etc).

But if I try to curl directly in Ubuntu (curl localhost/v1/someapi), then everything works.

I assume, that my problem with nginx configuration. Anyone knows, how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running nginx on the host or in a container? Also, I'm assuming you're opening port 4000:4000 in the container?

Comment: I'm running nginx on the host (just installed in Ubuntu), jersey app runs in docker container. Yes, I'm opening 4000:4000 port

Comment: How are you starting everything? Are you using docker-compose? Also, I know this doesn't answer your question, but it may lead to your answer. When ever I hear nginx - docker, I always point to this project: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy. It may not give you what you're looking for, but i may help with some configuration. PS -  this is setup to run nginx in a container as well.

Comment: No, I don't use docker-compose. Nginx not running in a container. Ok, I'll take a look to the project